# Não consigo exibir o resultado de um SELECT COUNT (MYSQL) na página HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou com um problema com o retorno de uma consulta MySQL.

Eu faço uma consulta que faz um SELECT count de um campo em um banco de dados. O problema é quando vou exibir o retorno da consulta no HTML, me retorna esse erro.

```
<?php       
    $select_pendentes = "SELECT count(codigo) from tbl_atividades WHERE STATUS = 'PENDENTE' AND RESPONSAVEL = 'BRUNO' AND month(DT_VENCIMENTO) = month(now())";
    $lista_pendentes = mysqli_query($conecta, $select_pendentes);


    if(!$lista_pendentes)
    {
        die("Erro no Banco - CONTAR ATIVIDADES PENDENTES");
    }
?>

<!-- EXIBIÇÃO NO HTML -->

<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2" id="resultados-dashboard">                   
<div class="col-lg-2 .relatorios" id="resultados-pendentes">
    <h1><?php echo $lista_pendentes; ?></h1>
    <p>Pendentes</p>
</div>
```

Imagem do Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema só acontece com a consulta. Se eu adicionar um valor ou um texto na variável $lista_pendentes, ela é exibida normalmente no HTML.

O resultado da query no console do MySQL acontece normalmente. Vejam abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando dar um `echo` no resultado vindo do banco, porém esse resultado é um objeto, e não uma string.

O problema está nessa linha:

```
<h1><?php echo $lista_pendentes; ?></h1>
```

Você teria que acessar os resultados utilizando:

```
<h1><?php echo $lista_pendentes->nome_do_atributo; ?></h1>
```

Caso queira ver a estrutura do objeto retornado pode utilizar:

```
<pre>
    <?php var_dump($lista_pendentes); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Valeu, Gabriel. Com base na sua resposta consegui ter uma luz aqui. Parece ser um erro bobo, mas já estava saturado e não estava conseguindo pensar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Thiago, Ali no sql você precisa determinar um alias (exemplo: **total**) para o count e depois chamar `$lista_pendentes['total']`.

Comment: Boa, Marcos. O interessante é que estudamos isso, mas a falta de prática faz esquecermos grande parte do que não utilizamos. Estava trabalhando com Front-End, e esqueci muito coisa do back.

Comment: Faz parte kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar mysql_num_rows (Recomendo migrar para MYSQLi aliás)

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-num-rows.html)

Seu código final será:

```
<?php       
    $select_pendentes = "SELECT count(codigo) from tbl_atividades WHERE STATUS = 'PENDENTE' AND RESPONSAVEL = 'BRUNO' AND month(DT_VENCIMENTO) = month(now())";
    $lista_pendentes = mysqli_query($conecta, $select_pendentes);


    if(!$lista_pendentes)
    {
        die("Erro no Banco - CONTAR ATIVIDADES PENDENTES");
    }
?>

<!-- EXIBIÇÃO NO HTML -->

<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2" id="resultados-dashboard">                   
<div class="col-lg-2 .relatorios" id="resultados-pendentes">
    <h1><?php echo mysql_num_rows($lista_pendentes); ?></h1>
    <p>Pendentes</p>
</div>
```